# jsonp string to number returning wrong number

Tags: javascript, json, object, numeric

For an app that requires data about poi's I retreive jsonp dat from a server. That data is in the following form:

```
{
"id":"31775",
"x1":"5.141329",
"y1":"51.593395",
"x2":"5.141974",
"y2":"51.593472",
"p1":"0",
"p2":"0"
}
```

Because the server runs php 5.2.17 I cannot use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`.

So when I have received the files I try to convert them to numbers. The chrome console and the converted numbers are however wrong as can be seen below.

```
Object {id: "31775", x1: "5.141329", y1: "51.593395", x2: "5.141974", y2: "51.593472"…}
id: "31775"
p1: "0"
p2: "0"
x1: 5.261592156887178
x2: 5.261092156887178
y1: 8736.838921620045
y2: 8736.836754225322
__proto__: Object
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this? In the mean time I have asked my hoster to upgrade the php version so we can use the numeric check.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I try to convert them to numbers"_ - How? Please show your code.

Comment: The data shown is in the Chrome console. So even before I try to convert it the numbers become messed up. As you can see, y1 turns from  the string 51.593395 to the number 8736.838921620045. I cannot replicate this behaviour in any other way, but it happens with all the data i receive...

Answer (score 0):

From my Chrome console:

```
var o = {
  "id":31775,
  "x1":5.141329,
  "y1":51.593395,
  "x2":5.141974,
  "y2":51.593472,
  "p1":0,
  "p2":0
};
```

JSON.stringify(o, null, 2)

"{
  "id": 31775,
  "x1": 5.141329,
  "y1": 51.593395,
  "x2": 5.141974,
  "y2": 51.593472,
  "p1": 0,
  "p2": 0
}"

If you are getting wildly different numbers, your convert from string to number is broken.

If you are getting slightly different numbers, then welcome to [http://floating-point-gui.de/](welcome to floating point).